# Connection Refused al intentar conectar a base de datos MySql

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando acceder a una Base de Datos MySQL desde una clase Java con el Driver JDBC, pero siempre me da la excepción **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.**

Esta sería mi clase Java (javaSQL.java):

```
package javasql;

import java.sql.*;

public class JavaSQL {

    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javasql";
    private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 

    private static Connection cnx = null;

    protected static void conectar() {
        if (cnx == null) {
            System.out.println("Conectando...");
            try {
                Class.forName(driver); 
                cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + ". Error de Conexion CE02");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + ". Error de Conexion CE01");
            } finally {
                if (cnx != null) System.out.println("Conectado con exito!!");
            } 
        }
    }

    protected static void desconectar() {
        if (cnx != null) {
            System.out.println("Desconectando...");

            try {
                cnx.close();
                cnx = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + ". Error de Desconexion DC01");
            } finally {
                if (cnx == null) System.out.println("Desconectado con exito!!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        conectar();
    }

}
```

Y esta es mi Base de Datos (db.sql):

```
create database javasql;

use javasql;

create table usuario (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(125) unique,
    password varchar(125),
    created_at datetime
);
```

No se qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal, pero la excepción que me tira es siempre esta:

```
Conectando...
Server connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect'.

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2921)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javasql.JavaSQL.conectar(JavaSQL.java:26)
    at javasql.JavaSQL.main(JavaSQL.java:53)

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: ¿Has tratado de conectar a la base de datos usando MySQL Workbench o algun otro programa cliente? Suena a que la base de datos no está corriendo.

Comment: Estoy con sstan, parece un problema de acceso a la base de datos más que de tu código. Prueba como te ha comentado sstan y prueba. Puede que no tengas levantado el servicio o algo así.

Comment: Otra idea: aparentemente existen problemas en Java usando IPv6, que tal vez es el caso aquí.  Puedes probar cambiando `localhost:3306` a `127.0.0.1:3306` y ver si cambia algo. Te dejo una referencia por su ayuda, y porque es posible que no estoy entendiendo bien la solución recomendada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219431/why-connection-to-localhost-is-refused.

Comment: sstan, Fernando, yo lo que he hecho ha sido directamente escribir el script SQL para la base de datos directamente desde el mismo Netbeans, igual que he hecho con la clase Java. ¿Así no vale?

Comment: Son cosas separadas. Primero que nada, asegúrate que tu base de datos está corriendo. Si lo has instalado como un servicio de Windows, puedes verificar en la lista de servicios de Windows si está en ejecución.

Comment: El siguiente paso para resolver tu problema sería iniciar una conexión a tu base de datos desde una herramienta como MySQL Workbench u otro cliente (tal como indica @sstan desde el primer comentario) para comprobar que sí te puedes conectar con los parámetros indicados en tu conexión.

Comment: Imagino que aquí tendrás un nombre de usuario y una password válidos para la BD: `cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");` aquí el usuario es "root" y la pwd está en blanco. Aparte de lo que otros han sugerido, si has verificado que la BD funciona, verifica si tus drivers JDBC están actualizados.

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto! No me acordaba de que tenía el XAMPP y he podido activar el servidor de MySQL desde el XAMPP. Ya me funciona correctamente. Gracias por vuestra ayuda!